# Finding resolution of an optical system using Rayleigh criterion

Tags: programming, mathematical-optimization, optics

I want to use the Rayleigh criterion to find the resolution of an optical system.  I have two functions `f1 = Sinc[x]^2` and `f2 = Sinc[x-T]^2`, `T` being the translation. I want to change the value of `T` until the first minimum of `f2` coincides with the maximum of `f1` (Rayleigh criterion). That being achieved, the value `x` and `T` should be returned.

Pseudocode:

- *for `x=100` translate `T` until the first minimum of `f2` coincides with the peak of `f1`; print `{x, T}`*
- *repeat the same procedure for `x=105` ... up to `x=200`.*

So, what I would like to do is basically start the program and generate a table with the values `x` and `T`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I think you would find it useful to review the documentation and basic tutorials. Mathematica uses square brackets for functions so your f1 and f2 definitions have the wrong syntax. Also, it is not good practice to use uppercase single letters  to name expressions as they can clash with built-in functions. Try using lower case `f` instead.

Comment: Just find the distance between the max and min ...

Comment: The Rayleigh criterion is for the first zero (not the first minimum) of f2 to coincide with the maximum of f1.

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that you were using $sinc(x)^2$, in which case the first minimum and first zero are the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do it the smart way just looking at the distance between max and min, but anyway this is the procedure for doing what you asked for

```
Maximize[Sinc[x - t /. (NMinimize[Sinc[t]^2, t][[2]])]^2, x]
```

> {1., {x -> -3.14159}}

**Edit**

```
Plot[{Sinc[x]^2, Sinc[x - t /. (NMinimize[Sinc[t]^2, t][[2]])]^2}, {x, -10, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi,

I have two functions Sinc[x1] and Sinc[x2-T], x100=1, x2 =200, T a real number;

Pseudocode: for x=100 translate T till the first min of f2 coincide with peak of f1 print print {x1, T} repeat the same procedure for x=105

That would be all!

Thanks in advance everyone

Comment: @Darwin. Edit your **question** to add your clarifications. Don't add them as a comment to an answer.

Comment: hi, if i change the question, then anybody reading the thread would not understand the discussion following it

Comment: @Darwin The usual procedure is leaving the existing question as it is now and add modifications at the end (after an edit title)

Comment: @belisarius I restated the question

Comment: @Darwin see the answer now

Comment: It doesnt satisfy my need of getting a table of values after running it, but thanks anyway

Comment: +1 for trying to answer a moving-target question.

Comment: @Jens, i must admit this has been a moving-target question. In future i ll be preciser. Thanks again everyone :)